# FTP Connection Refused

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, ftp

I am on a Windows XP machine that is trying to connect to a Windows 2008 FTP. When trying to connect to my ftp site, I am getting a `ftp: connect :Connection refused`. I have confirmed that other machines are able to connect to the FTP and transfer data.

I have a batch file doing the FTPing:

[image]

I've taken the following steps to try to remedy the situation:

- ping: I am able to ping and receive a response from my FTP server
- tracert: I was able to do a full tracert and was able to get to my client machine to the host
- firewall: There are no firewalls enabled on this machine
- other FTP: I am **unable** to connect to any other FTP site
- telnet: I am able to telnet to port 21.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

edit: What I did notice that when I do a `netstat`, I see that port 21 is being occupied by `PID 1256`:

[image]

Now, if I check my task manager, I see 1256 is `inetinfo.exe`.

Comment: The FTP service runs in the inetinfo.exe process so your netstat output is what I would expect.

Comment: @joeqwerty would stopping that process remedy my problem?

Comment: No, that would stop the FTP service. The FTP services runs in the inetinfo.exe process, which is perfectly normal and expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since other machines are able to connect to the FTP server I see two possible causes:

- The XP machine IP address has been automatically (or manually) banned or blacklisted, causing the FTP server to reject any connection from this IP
- A firewall or other IP filtering software is running on the XP machine and block the connection to the FTP server

Yet it's strange that you are able to telnet from the XP machine to the FTP server on port 21.

Comment: Could there be some sort of port blocking on the firewall/hardware level?

Comment: yes, firewall is all about blocking port. Now Windows XP built-in firewall allow all outgoing connections by default I think. Do you have any other firewall software on the XP box or on the network?

Comment: It might be on the network level. This box is sitting on someone else's network.

Answer (score 0):

The other machines that can connect are also XP machines? Maybe your machine has FTP disabled? If you open a command prompt and type FTP does the ftp> come up?

Comment: Yes it does, `ftp>` comes up.

Comment: Is it possibly a firewall issue?

Comment: I found a site giving a ton of commands to trouble shoot FTP but it's for linux

Comment: [Maybe it can help you](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ftp-connection-refused-error-solution-to-problem/)